# Problema al mostrar datos en PHP desde una tabla MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy haciendo un sistema de llaves para un torneo, donde quiero mostrar los datos ordenadamente, por ejemplo, tengo ya el diseño creado (adjunto imagen)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo solo me muestra el nombre que está en el row 1 del select que hago en mysql, el select de mysql se ve así

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_FILTRO_JUV_68_FEM_K_COL()
BEGIN
    SELECT NOMBRE_AT, NOM_ACADEMIA_AT FROM ATLETA WHERE ANO_NAC_AT <= 2007 AND ANO_NAC_AT >= 2005 AND CAT_PESO_AT = '-68' AND SEXO_AT = 'F' AND CATEGORIA_AT = 'K' AND CINT_CAT_AT = 'COLOR';
END//
```

El output de ese select es este,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La forma en como muestro los valores es la siguiente, primero cuento el número de rows para saber donde poner los datos, segundo, creo una variable con el valor true para luego pasarlo a false y que el diseño no se imprima varias veces, luego hago un if donde le digo que si el total de rows es 2 entonces se imprima de tal forma, dentro de ese if le paso un foreach con los datos y al final paso la variable de registro a false para que no se imprima varias veces el html, sería de esta forma:

```
function FILTRO_JUV_68_FEM_K_COL_CONTROLLER(){
    $llave = FILTRO_JUV_68_FEM_K_COL_MODEL();
    $numParticipantes = mysqli_num_rows($llave);
    $registro = true;
    if($totalResult = 2){
        foreach ($llave as $item){
            if($registro){
                echo
                '
                <a href="#FILTRO_JUV_68_FEM_K_COL"></a>
                <h4>Kyorugui femenino juvenil -68kg cinturón de color</h4>
                <main id="tournament">
                    <ul class="round round-1">
                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top"><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom "><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top"><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom "><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top "><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom"><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top"><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom "><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top"><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom "><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top"><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom "><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top"><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom "><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top"><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom "><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="round round-2">
                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top"><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom "><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top"><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom "><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top "><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom"><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top "><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom"><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="round round-3">
                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top"><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom "><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top "><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom"><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="round round-4">
                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top">'.$item["NOMBRE_AT"].'<span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom ">'.$item["NOMBRE_AT"].'<span></span></li>
                        
                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                    </ul>   
                    <ul class="round round-5">
                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top"><span></span></li>
                        
                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                    </ul>   
                    ';
                    $registro = false;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

La idea es que en el span vaya el nombre de los atletas por eso le paso el dato, sin embargo, se muestra el nombre repetido porque solo está mostrando el nombre del row 1 y no del row 2.

Answer (score 1):

La forma en que lo logré es creando un array donde se almacenan los nombres de los atletas y luego imprimo ese array con el número del dato según se necesite, de la siguiente forma:

```
function FILTRO_JUV_68_FEM_K_COL_CONTROLLER(){
    $llave = FILTRO_JUV_68_FEM_K_COL_MODEL();
    $numParticipantes = mysqli_num_rows($llave);
    $registro = true;
    $nombre_at = array();
    $nombre_aca = array();
    $cont = 0;
    while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($llave)){
        $nombre_at[$cont] = $item["NOMBRE_AT"];
        $nombre_aca[$cont] = $item["NOM_ACADEMIA_AT"];
        $cont++;
    } 

    if($numParticipantes == 2){

                echo
                '
                <a id="FILTRO_JUV_68_FEM_K_COL"></a>
                <h4>Kyorugui femenino juvenil -68kg cinturón de color</h4>
                <main id="tournament">
                    <ul class="round round-1">
                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top"><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom "><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top"><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom "><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top "><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom"><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top"><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom "><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top"><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom "><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top"><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom "><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top"><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom "><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top"><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom "><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="round round-2">
                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top"><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom "><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top"><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom "><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top "><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom"><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top "><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom"><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="round round-3">
                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top"><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom "><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top "><span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom"><span></span></li>

                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="round round-4">
                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top">'.$nombre_at[0].' / '.$nombre_aca[0].' <span></span></li>
                        <li class="game game-spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="game game-bottom">'.$nombre_at[1].' / '.$nombre_aca[1].' <span></span></li>
                        
                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                    </ul>   
                    <ul class="round round-5">
                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                        
                        <li class="game game-top"><span></span></li>
                        
                        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
                    </ul>   

                    </main>
                    ';
        
    }
}
```